# how to find cache access trace of a process?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I want to know the contents of the cache while a specific process is executing, assuming only this process is running currently. Is there any tool which can help me? or some y.mechanism? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible using a normal OS, but it is definitely possible if you run your process on a simulator. There are many architectural simulators available, some examples are SimpleScalar (written in C), and Simics (written in python). These simulators give you access to all the architectural details and states, etc. You could try that out.